# Reloading SWF a second time gets an error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I'm having an odd issue with reloading SWFS.
I start of with loading my SWF:

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest( "RegionalIntro.swf" ); 
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
req.data = true; // POST requests require non-null data 

introSWF = new Loader();
introSWF.load(req);
addChild(introSWF);
```

Then once I'm finished I unload:

```
removeChild(introSWF);
introSWF.unloadAndStop(true);
```

Now when I want to reload the SWF I run the first bit of code again I get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

I cant work out why I'd get that the second time it loads and not the first. It's supposed to just be the same?
This is being done inside Windows Projector .exe file, it's going to run as a kiosk application.

EDIT:

```
at com.company.THPassport.exRegional::exRegionalIntro/skipTablet()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at com.company.THPassport.exRegional::exRegionalLoader/userLoaded()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at com.company.THPassport.utilities.DB::user/loadUserData()
at com.company.THPassport.utilities.DB::user/checkExistingUserLoadedXML()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

As far as I can see it's getting an error from here:

```
currentUser = e.data;

maxspeechB.parent.removeChild(maxspeechB);
maxspeechA.parent.removeChild(maxspeechA);
wallstageA.parent.removeChild(wallstageA);
tabletfalls.parent.removeChild(tabletfalls);
tabletvanishes.parent.removeChild(tabletvanishes);

wallfills.alpha = 0;
    if (currentUser.getCompleteAreas() == 1) {
        wallfills.gotoAndStop(40);
    } else if (currentUser.getCompleteAreas() == 2) {
        wallfills.gotoAndStop(80);
    } else if (currentUser.getCompleteAreas() == 3) {
        wallfills.gotoAndStop(120);
    }
wallstageB.alpha = 1;
Tweener.addTween(wallfills,{  alpha:1, time:1, transition:  "linear", onComplete:dropSignpost});
```

What I can't work out is why that works the first time, but when it's reloaded it doesn't work?

EDIT2: The plot thickens, I can catch the error by surrounding all of the code in the function at the top of the stack trace with a try/catch block. I trace the error and its the same, the weird thing is all the code executes as expected. All works fine and throws an error ... very odd! I'd hate to leave it like this without finding out why it's doing it though ...

Comment: you run the exact same code when reloading the SWF?

Comment: I do. It's inside a function to load the intro so I call that function again.

Comment: Ben, a few questions... in line 5 of your code, why don't you start with `var introSWF:Loader = new Loader()` (In other words, have you previously initialized it?) Also, have you tried commmenting out various portions of code to see it you still get the error? That should help you determin whether it's the loading (or unloading) that's causing the error. Last, why are you using the POST method if you're not actually sending anything?

Comment: It's initialised at the top of the class as I access it in a couple of functions. The post method was recommended to make sure nothing was being cached. I don't really understand what it's meant to do but it's not broken anything so i've left it there for now. Do I not need it?

Comment: what line do you get the null object reference on?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a complete event listener to the `loader.contentLoaderInfo` and do everything below `loader.load` (like `addChild(introSWF);`)in the event listener handler. Even if not required, it helps you prevent the situation in which you are trying to use an object that hasn't load yet.

Comment: I may have done that a slightly backwards way. (This is my first big project since picking up an AS3 book) What I've done is in the doc class for the loaded SWF I've added to the constructor an eventlistener for ADDED_TO_STAGE that triggers an init function, this dispatches an event to tell the parent SWF its ready for data and to remove certain things from the stage. Is this the same as what you've said in a different way?

Comment: Also just tried adding that incase I was doing it wrong and I still receive the error ...

Comment: you were doing basically the same thing (because the loader adds the loaded content to the display only after it gets loaded), but definitely not a best practice :)

Comment: OK, I'll go through an update to the correct way, Thanks. Any other ideas on what my problem could be?

Comment: My best advice to you is to use the debugger to see exactly which object is null when you try to access it

Comment: Could you explain how I'd do this? My knowledge has some fairly big holes and debugging is one of them...

Answer (score 0):

Ben - is there a second line to that error? It might tell you that the error is thrown by the "RegionalIntro.swf", not your wrapper swf.

It's possible that something's going on in that SWF that's timing related. In other words - it might utilize some asset that needs to be loaded/initialized before it's called, and sometimes, it isn't ready yet.

Comment: I've added an edit. That function I've shown is only called once that loaded SWF has said it's been added to stage. Tracing the objects I'm removing, or the properties I use show that they are there.